# JedisConnectionFactory setHostName is deprecated

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis

This will be my first time connecting Spring to Redis. The documentation for jedis connection factory: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

Offers the following code:

```
@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory
            = new JedisConnectionFactory();

    jedisConFactory.setHostName("localhost");
    jedisConFactory.setPort(6379);
    return jedisConFactory;
}
```

Looks great, but my IDE is telling me that the setHostName and setPort methods have been deprecated (even though I'm using the versions from the tutorial).

I was wondering if anyone had a simple "get spring data connected to redis" example that uses the non-deprecated API calls?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

With Spring Data Redis 2.0, those methods have been deprecated.
You now need to configure using RedisStandaloneConfiguration

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html#setHostName-java.lang.String-

Example:

```
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("yourRedisPasswordIfAny"));
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: So application.properties [spring configuration vars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) like `spring.redis.password` and `spring.redis.host` won't work, you have to configure them via code?

Comment: @xref Some applications may have multiple redis connection at the same time hence have to configure it programmatically.

Answer (score 29):

```
@Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("localhost");
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(0);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("password"));

        JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));// 60s connection timeout

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration,
                jedisClientConfiguration.build());

        return jedisConFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the details about jedisClientConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the response by @Thang Le

You can configure your time out of read operations, adding this line:

> jedisClientConfigurationBuilder.readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

This is the value that you can obtain when use:

> jedisConFactory.getTimeout()